# delete some google drive files in a folder by search

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, drive

I'm trying to delete some files from my drive using this:

```
function deleteFiles(){
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title:720p');
  Logger.log(files);
  //Logger.log(files.next().getName);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
   // files.next().setTrashed(true);
    //Logger.log(files.next().getName());
    Logger.log('hola');
  }
}
```

But i get `Error: Invalid argument:q` in all commented lines, even in the while loop. The first logger shows Folder Iterator, so every should be fine...

Files exist! and all have different names, but they have in common "720p" in their names.

Besides, and i haven't been able to implement this yet, i only need to delete these files that are only in one specific folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your searchterm is in the middle or at the end of the file name or title. Try using this, it seems to work for me.
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters

```js
function deleteFiles() {
  var searchTerm = "12345test"
  var searchFor ="fullText contains '" + searchTerm + "'"; //single quotes are needed around searchterm
 var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor); 
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   Logger.log(file.getName());
  // file.setTrashed(true)
 }
}
```

Comment: yeah kep in mind it will find any file that has that term inside as well

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution, but it is not efficient, please feel free to provide a more efficient one:

```
function deleteFiles(){    
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('MyFolder').next();
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) { 
    var file = files.next();
    var filename = file.getName();
    if (filename.indexOf("720p")>-1){
    Logger.log(filename);
    file.setTrashed(true);  
    }     
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

could try something like this-

```js
function deleteFiles() {
// Log the name of every file named "12345test" in the user's Drive.
 var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('12345test');
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   Logger.log(file.getName());
  // file.setTrashed(true)
 }
}
```

Comment: hi, i can't use getFilesbyName, because there are a lot of files with different filenames, but all have in common "720p" in them... Search by extension could help too...

Comment: I added a new answer

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Advanced Drive Service and the Query option "title contains xxxx"

Comment: i've tried that, but sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't (even though i haven't changed anything in drive). Is there a way to search by extension?

Comment: i can't use anything described there, all my searchs give 0 results... my search should be: `name contains '720p' and 'folderid' in parents`.

Answer (score 0):

here is another way, using searchFiles technique

```js
function deleteFiles() {
  var searchTerm = "12345test"
  var searchFor ="title contains '" + searchTerm + "'"; //single quotes are needed around searchterm
 var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor); 
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   Logger.log(file.getName());
  // file.setTrashed(true)
 }
}
```

Comment: It works fine for me- what type of file and name are you searching for I can try to duplicate? If you create a file named 12345test does it work?

Comment: namesfiles are: this.is.the.file.number.1.720p.ext. I tried the search with other files, but nothing works, except `name contains 'pdf'`that give me all my pdf files....

Comment: I see what is happening now- It is searching from the leftmost of the title. - See answer #3